# How to decode json without knowing the key/name string?

Tags: java, android, json

I am receiving a json string in the following format:

```
{"27":{"id":"27","uid":"4","title":"teamer.zapto.org","url":"www.google.jo","ip":"74.125.234.63","enabled":"1","services":{"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058071"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"},

"30":{"id":"30","uid":"4","title":"google","url":"www.google.com","ip":"74.125.234.114","enabled":"1","services":{"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058079"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"},

"31":{"id":"31","uid":"4","title":"facebook.com","url":"facebook.com","ip":"69.171.247.21","enabled":"1","services":{"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058095"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"},

"32":{"id":"32","uid":"4","title":"ebir","url":"www.ebir.com","ip":"74.52.50.226","enabled":"1","services":{"Ftp":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058073"},"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058073"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"},

"33":{"id":"33","uid":"4","title":"zapto","url":"teamer.zapto.org","ip":"200.35.150.6","enabled":"1","services":{"Http 1":{"status":"0","ts":"1355056146"}},"fetch_interval":"3600","ping_shift":"2"},

"35":{"id":"35","uid":"4","title":"vogella.com","url":"vogella.com","ip":"46.163.79.226","enabled":"1","services":{"Ftp":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058098"},"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058098"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"},

"36":{"id":"36","uid":"4","title":"msn","url":"www.msn.com","ip":"131.253.13.140","enabled":"1","services":{"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058103"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"},

"37":{"id":"37","uid":"4","title":"dubizzle.com","url":"www.dubizzle.com","ip":"94.236.93.152","enabled":"1","services":{"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058068"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"},

"38":{"id":"38","uid":"4","title":"olx.jo","url":"olx.jo","ip":"204.74.99.100","enabled":"1","services":{"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058108"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"},

"40":{"id":"40","uid":"4","title":"www.sukar.com","url":"www.sukar.com","ip":"72.52.8.195","enabled":"1","services":{"Ftp":{"status":"0","ts":"1355058092"},"Http 1":{"status":"1","ts":"1355058092"}},"fetch_interval":"60","ping_shift":"0"}}
```

as you can see the keys are numbers (27, 30, 31,...) and are not consecutive. How can I get the data from such json? I know that it must be some kind of loop depending on length but I couldn't figure it out on how to do so. Usually I'd use `jObject.getString("id")`, but since I don't know what the string would be what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `for (var key in json) {
  // ...
}` doesn't work?

Comment: @gkris this is not java syntax, is it?

Comment: @gkris probably not in Java

Comment: @PradeepSimha I believe that would be `for(String key: json)`, and only if `json` iterates a collection of keys. I think `Map`s iterate over their entries, not keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JSONObject questionMark = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    Iterator keys = questionMark.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
    // loop to get the dynamic key
    String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();

    // get the value of the dynamic key
    JSONObject currentDynamicValue = questionMark.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);
```

Comment: Even better, with an iterator.

Comment: ill try this too, but what's an iterator a class of some sort?

Comment: Iterator takes the place of Enumeration

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `JSONObject` as the root, you should be able to do the following:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray names = root.names();
for(int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++) {
    String tag = names.getString(i);
    ...
}
```

The `tag` will be the numeric tag you refer to.

Comment: what is root.name() and how to define it

Comment: As I said, root is a `JSONObject`. `root.names()` is a method of `JSONObject`.

Comment: the weird thing is that it is in the following order (30, 32, 40, 31, 35, 36, 33, 27, 37, 38) when i did Log.v("tag: ", tag.trim().toString()  + ""); but as long that i have them all no problem.